# Layout overflow components

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem when my strings in my `TextView`s grow and overflows, sometimes hiding the text of another `TextView` or starting to disappear.

I would like it to work like this (I know this looks a lot like swings `FlowLayout` but not quite since it's alignment isn't fixed, one component is left and the other right aligned):

```
 -------------------------------------
|[TextView0]               [TextView1]|
 -------------------------------------
```

And when the text grows:

```
    TextView0 grows:                        TextView1 grows:
 -------------------------------------    -------------------------------------
|[TextView0 TextView0 TextView0]      |  |[TextView0]                          |
|                          [TextView1]|  |      [TextView1 TextView1 TextView1]|
 -------------------------------------    -------------------------------------
```

- Could it be done with existing layouts (maybe using a combination of layouts)?
- If I do need to construct a new layout I would like to have a working example.

---

I have tried `ReleativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` but never got it to work:

1. **`RelativeLayout`:**

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextView0"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:text="TextView0" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:text="TextView1" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

   When the text the start to **overlap** which I tried to fix with `TextView0` being `toLeftOf="TextView1"`. But in that case `TextView0` disappears.
2. **`LinearLayout`**:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextView0"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView0" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/TextView1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="right"
           android:text="TextView1" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   Here the `TextView`s start to interfere and when `TextView0` gets the full width `TextView1` disappears (its width goes towards zero).

Comment: Have you tried using `weight`s with the `LinearLayout`? Give each `TextView` a `layout_weight` of say 1 and if you want space in between then set an empty `View` to have whatever `weight` you want like `.5`? Then I believe they should grow in `height` but not `width`, unless I missed something

Comment: Yes, `LinearLayout` only seem to use one line/column, so in the end I don't _think_ it's what I want. Also, I want it to be dynamic so that `TextView0`s can take up space when `TextView1` is tiny. Settings a weight makes it fixed (or?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an attempt to create a layout for this purpose.

*It works like I discuss in the original question but feel free to update the answer if you make it better!*

```
public class KeyValueLayout extends ViewGroup {

    public KeyValueLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public KeyValueLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public KeyValueLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, 
                          int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int paddRight = getPaddingRight();
        int paddLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int paddBottom = getPaddingBottom();
        int paddWidth = paddRight + paddLeft;

        int sizeWidth  = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - paddWidth;
        int sizeHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - paddWidth;

        int modeWidth  = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int modeHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

        int modeW = modeWidth == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY 
                        ? MeasureSpec.AT_MOST : modeWidth;
        int modeH = modeHeight == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY 
                        ? MeasureSpec.AT_MOST : modeHeight;

        // where the next view should be placed
        int lineYPosition = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ) {

            View key = getChildAt(i++);

            key.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(sizeWidth, modeW),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(sizeHeight, modeH)
            );

            LayoutParams keyLp = (LayoutParams) key.getLayoutParams();
            keyLp.setPosition(paddLeft, lineYPosition);

            if (i >= getChildCount()) 
                break;

            View val = getChildAt(i++);

            val.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(sizeWidth, modeW),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(sizeHeight, modeH)
            );

            LayoutParams valLp = (LayoutParams) val.getLayoutParams();

            int valXPosition = paddLeft + sizeWidth - val.getMeasuredWidth();

            // check if both fit on the same line
            if (key.getMeasuredWidth() + val.getMeasuredWidth() <= sizeWidth) {

                valLp.setPosition(valXPosition, lineYPosition);

                lineYPosition += Math.max(key.getMeasuredHeight(), 
                                          val.getMeasuredHeight());
            } else {

                // not enough room, make some space 
                lineYPosition += key.getMeasuredHeight();

                valLp.setPosition(valXPosition, lineYPosition);

                lineYPosition += val.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        }

        int controlMaxLength = sizeWidth + paddRight; 
        int controlMaxThickness = lineYPosition + paddBottom;

        int resolvedWidth = resolveSize(controlMaxLength, widthMeasureSpec);
        int resolvedHeight =resolveSize(controlMaxThickness,heightMeasureSpec);
        this.setMeasuredDimension(resolvedWidth, resolvedHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            child.layout(lp.x, lp.y, 
                         lp.x + child.getMeasuredWidth(), 
                         lp.y + child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return p instanceof LayoutParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return new LayoutParams(p);
    }

    public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams {

        private int x;
        private int y;

        public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
            super(context, attributeSet);
        }

        public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
            super(width, height);
        }

        public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams) {
            super(layoutParams);
        }

        public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<nu.wen.android.layout.KeyValueLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/example_string_long"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/example_string_short" />
</nu.wen.android.layout.KeyValueLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best lib for that [Android-FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)
its simple, easy to use and awesome.

Comment: Does that work with different alignment of the components? One is left and the other right aligned. Cannot tell from looking at the [home page](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) (all are left aligned in the examples).

Comment: no only left alignment, but you can change it easily and add the right alignment, i have done that before. check my Gist https://gist.github.com/JafarKhQ/6582532

Comment: That would change *all* components. In my case I want only one of the components to be right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "yes" - because it is just software, anything can be done :). However, I don't think you can achieve it with any standard layout.

So my best bet is that you create your own View class and then layout things in whatever way you want. You may want to read this (if you have not) as a starting point:

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way. :) If you only would have suggested to do a custom *layout* I would be a little happier... ;)

Comment: Funny thing about Android is that "layout" is just a View. You may also what to read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Because I suggested that you build your own customize View class. That means you can extends View or any of its subclass, including "layout" such as LinearLayout, RelativeLayout... Or perhaps I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: I can build my own GUI also from scratch, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: OK, I think I now understand your comment - sorry I misunderstood before. You probably wants to know the exact class that you should extends.

Comment: Something like that, I would like to know how I can do it. Not if it can be done, I know that! :)

Comment: If I would do it, I would look at the code of the AbsoluteLayout. It is deprecated but it will probably give us some good idea. Then I would just extends View itself, and overrides methods such as "onMeasure" and "onLayout"... You probably do not need any of existing Layout, since none of them fit your purpose and they are very generic, while you have quite a concrete design in your mind.